# How to Pass JSON parameters and authorization using superagent library in MOCHA framework?

Tags: javascript, json, node.js, mocha.js

I am trying to do API testing. For that I have created a code to trigger POST API and then to generate test-results. For that I am using Mocha.js testing framework and want to use SuperAgent library to trigger the API and get the response.

```
Here is the code:

var assert = require("assert");
var superagent = require("superagent");
var should = require("should");
var expect = require('expect');
var chai = require('chai');
var chaiHttp = require('chai-http');
var request=require('request');

describe('creating an Incident', function() {

    it('should pass the parameters needed for creating an Incident', function(done) {

superagent
      .post('http://localhost:9001/incident/create' )
       .send({user: 'user123',password: 'pass123'}) //authorization details

      .set('Accept', 'application/json')  //headers
      .set('Content-Type', 'application/json')  //headers

      .send({ Name:'MyIncident', orderId:'12340508'}) //JSON parameters to be passed for creating an incident.

      .end(function(err, res) {

        expect(200,done); //Status code
             if (err) {
               throw err;
                     }
              else {
               res.should.have.status(400);
               done(); 
                  }
         });
    });

});
```

Now, the problem is while running this code on command prompt, I am getting this error. Please have a look.

[image: Command Prompt Showing Error]

Please suggest changes which I need to do in this program. 
Thanks in advance :)

Comment: My _guess_ is that you're calling `.send()` twice, and the second call will overwrite the first call (with the credentials).

Comment: So what should I do? As, I need to pass both of them. :(

Comment: One `.send()` with all values in one object?

Answer (score 0):

It depends how you implemented authentication in your server-side code. I implemented something similar with the help of [passport](http://passportjs.org/) and its local strategy, which requires a persistent login session.
For testing purposes I use supertest and [supertest-session](https://www.npmjs.com/package/supertest-session) to create a valid user session in the before hook. Some example from supertest-session documentation:

```
var session = require('supertest-session');
var myApp = require('../../path/to/app');

var testSession = null;

beforeEach(function () {
    testSession = session(myApp);
});

it('should fail accessing a restricted page', function (done) {
    testSession.get('/restricted')
        .expect(401)
        .end(done)
});

it('should sign in', function (done) {
    testSession.post('/signin')
        .send({ username: 'foo', password: 'password' })
        .expect(200)
        .end(done);
});

it('should get a restricted page', function (done) {
    testSession.get('/restricted')
        .expect(200)
        .end(done)
});
```